# Convert data to matrix form

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a text file like this picture shown.

[image]

I want to import the data into the matlab and convert it into matrix form like this:

```
[-5.02 9.70 -1.00 4.68;-2.34 7.53 2.51 3.51;7.03 7.36 6.02 -0.33]
```

Is there any way to do this nicely?

Comment: does one of these answers was useful? If so, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`dlmread`](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/matlab/techdoc/ref/dlmread.html)?
See this [example](https://alenblog.wordpress.com/2011/03/27/matlab-read-matrix-data-from-a-file/).

In your case:

```
 M = dlmread(filename,'\t',1,0);
```

Parameter Row = 1 to skip first line.

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a tab separated values file (just like yours, but without column names), and then used load function to obtain the matrix:

```
X = load('file.txt')
```

After this you will have matrix in X, as if you executed

```
X = [-5.02 9.70 -1.00 4.68;-2.34 7.53 2.51 3.51;7.03 7.36 6.02 -0.33]
```

Please don't forget to remove the first line (with column names) before loading the file.

The adventure of load function is that is automatically parse file. For instance it can parse the file where spaces, tabs, columns are used for separating columns.